# how to use webpack define a function to dynamic require files

Tags: angularjs, require, webpack, lazy-loading

I code a lazyLoadModule function, which is used to loazyLoad angular.js modules.But I found that webpack will require all files in '../modules/' directory, the reason maybe is that `var mod = require("../modules/" + module);` executed. I want require files when call the function in router resolve.

lazyload.js:

```js
exports.lazyLoadModule = function(module){
  var resolver = {
    'lazyLoad': ['$q', '$ocLazyLoad', function($q, $ocLazyLoad){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      require.ensure([], function (require) {
        var mod = require("../modules/" + module);
        $ocLazyLoad.load({
          name: mod.name,
        });
        deferred.resolve();
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }]
  }
  return resolver;
}
```

app.js:

```js
var lazyLoadModule = require('../util/lazyLoad.js').lazyLoadModule;
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'ngMaterial']);
angular.module('app')
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: '/home',
          template: require('../modules/home/template/home.html'),
          resolve: lazyLoadModule('home/home.js')
        })
        .state('biz1', {
          url: '/biz1',
          template: require('../modules/biz1/template/biz1.html'),
          resolve: lazyLoadModule('biz1/biz1.js')
        })
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
      $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    }
  ]);
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app'], {
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bundle-loader](https://github.com/webpack/bundle-loader) to do this:

```
(require('bundle?name=[path]!../modules/' + module))(function(mod) {
});
```

This will build every file inside the modules directory as a separate chunk, because of the `name=[path]` parameter.

Comment: 'build every file inside the modules directory as a separate chunk', I hope separate bundle file according to the module parameter. Just like this question https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1667

Comment: Yes. A [chunk](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) is a separate file that is loaded on demand. Because of the name=[path] parameter, each chunk's name will be the path of the file, so it will include the value of the module variable. So each file in '../modules/' will get its own chunk.